# How to conditionally apply gzip directive in Caddy?

Tags: gzip, caddy, caddyfile, breach-attack

I am trying to configure Caddy to only use gzip when the Referer header matches a particular domain. This is in order to mitigate a potentially BREACH attack.

However, I do not see a way inside of a Caddyfile that allows me to conditionally turn on gzip based on the value of a header.

The gzip directive here:

https://caddyserver.com/docs/gzip

Only allows conditional application based on path or file extension.

Hopefully this doesn't involve writing a custom directive?

```
:3333

# How to conditionally apply the following line?
gzip
```

Comment: Are you trying to apply gzip based on the request or response headers?

Comment: My understanding is that "The Referer request header contains the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed." thus it would always be on the request header to Caddy. What would another scenario be? So yes, I am interested in conditionally responding based on the request header and not the response header.

Comment: This might be possible with a `rewrite` hack for now, but a future version of Caddy will allow you to do this directly. Stay tuned!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a rewrite hack?

Comment: Do you have any other mechanisms for mitigating a BREACH attack? I read of some modules in nginx which would append a random length string to the body of the response, however, that obviously has its own drawbacks in the sense that it prevents caching.